# Is : any operator?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

If I put this line into JavaScript console (you do not need to declare "foo")

```
foo : 4;
```

What exactly this line means? Does "foo" live in any context? Is : any operator?

Comment: `label : statement` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Hi @user3078850, if the answer I provided has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

From the docs:

> The labeled statement can be used with break or continue statements.
>   It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

In other programming languages like C labels are used often with the [goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) statement. JavaScript do not have `goto`. In javaScript it can be used with `break` or `continue` statements.

The example from the docs using a labeled `continue` with for loops:

```
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i === 1 && j === 1) {
         continue loop1;
      }
      console.log('i = ' + i + ', j = ' + j);
   }
}

// Output is:
//   "i = 0, j = 0"
//   "i = 0, j = 1"
//   "i = 0, j = 2"
//   "i = 1, j = 0"
//   "i = 2, j = 0"
//   "i = 2, j = 1"
//   "i = 2, j = 2"
// Notice how it skips both "i = 1, j = 1" and "i = 1, j = 2"
```